# Does the order of operators in the the hamiltonian in second quantised form matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, second-quantization

For a particles that not interact (free particles) we can write the Hamiltonian in second quantized form as

$$\hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int \psi^{\dagger}(\vec{x}) \nabla^2 \psi(\vec{x}) d^3x \, .$$

Here $\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{x})$ and  $\psi(\vec{x})$ are field operators.

Does the order of the operators, $\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{x})$ , $\psi(\vec{x})$ and $\nabla^2$ matter? Is it alright to change the order of these operators?

Comment: Of course the order of operators matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters. $\nabla^2$ represents a derivative, so rearranging is as silly as saying something like this is true in general $$f(x) \frac{d}{dx} h(x) = h(x) \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x) h(x) \frac{d}{dx} = \cdots$$

Comment: I don't believe that that is the right analogy; the question was about rearranging *operators*, not the bringing functions in front of operators. A better analogy might be e.g. $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dy} \neq \frac{d}{dy}\frac{d}{dx}$ generally, but even that requires some explanation because it *does* hold true in many cases.